# Problem installing QGIS Valmeira on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit

Tags: qgis

I have been having trouble installing QGIS Valmeira on Windows 7 Professional with SP1. When I installed to the default directory C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\, many of the predefined coordinate projections were not loaded. Several other projections were listed in French.

At Andre's suggestion I then reinstalled to a folder without blanks such as C:\QGIS_Valmeira. This worked fine and brought in the previously missing projections.

I did not have this problem with earlier versions of QGIS like Lisboa. What is going on here? Is this a bug in version 2? If so, it must be causing problems for many other Windows users of QGIS.

Comment: I'm sure there would be lots more people complaining if this was the case, I didn't have any of these problems on Win8.1 x64 with either QGIS 2.0 or 2.2 using the default installation path "C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour" (or Valmiera)

Comment: I have the same problem with a Win7 home edition. I just have a few coordinate projection. The irritating thing is that the same installation works on another win7 professional fine. Both installation directories are d:\QGis

Comment: Sounds like quietely the same problem: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92772/problems-with-projections-in-qgis-2-2-on-a-windows-vista

Answer (score 1):

From your deleted answer to another question:

```
I am experiencing the same problem with Windows 7 Professional SP1. I am missing several projections, including EPSG:4326, while others are being listed in French.

I have tried both 32-bit and 64-bit installations, as follows:

QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.2.0-1-Setup-x86.exe and QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.2.0-1-Setup-x86_64.exe

The postinstall.log file for the 64-bit install shows the following, starting at line 93:

'"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 
 OSGEO4W home is C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera
 Synchronizing CRS database with GDAL/PROJ definitions.
 Load srs db from: C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS Valmiera/apps/qgis/./resources/srs.db
 QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified 
 QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
 QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
 QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
 QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
 Loading epsg.wkt 0 WKTs loaded
 CRS update (inserted:0 updated:0 deleted:3631 errors:0)
 No CRS updates were necessary.
```

The CRS synchronization breaks because of the blank after QGIS. The OSGEO4W home vaiable should not contain any blanks. For me, it reads C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\

It might be related to this ticket:

https://hub.qgis.org/issues/9409 and probably also https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10001